# How do I access a BigNumer in a transaction object?

Tags: bignumber

I am struggling to simply access the `BigNumber` Object from the `gasPrice` in Javascript. Currently, I am storing the whole transaction to a variable called `result`, and want to be able to `console.log(result.gasPrice.(somethingHere))`, and have it return the `BigNumber` Object as a hex string.

```
{
  hash: '0x7917b25d974da57425b156a36af1b3c9c58502d1ac71905c5270dbf9eb4d2e6d',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  transactionIndex: null,
  confirmations: 0,
  from: '0x2a73D57f0409B9Be6126C28f27Aa753b334Ee5bD',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x028fa6ae00', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x540ae480', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x028fa6ae00', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x03415f', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x52d24fdb80bd', _isBigNumber: true },
  nonce: 4,
  data: '0xfb3bdb4100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000152d02c7e14af680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000002a73d57f0409b9be6126c28f27aa753b334ee5bd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000619127d90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc200000000000000000000000016631e53c20fd2670027c6d53efe2642929b285c',
  r: '0x48c834ade1f104d7f7cf17f609b74f9a39c7c5f98d7bf8f81641900b2ddfde9d',
  s: '0x5dd2694318af863cf838c47a7d14c9a1f2fb2a28395ed17f07efccc669548ec3',
  v: 0,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 1,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out I was being an idiot b/c I am tired AF, remember to take breaks when coding kids! But if anyone needs the answer to help them out.
web3.utils.fromWei(transaction.value.toString())

Answer (score 0):

There is a function on these BigNumber objects, that lets you convert to a regular JS number:

```js
result.gasPrice.toNumber();
```

This returns a normal number, that you are used to working with in JavaScript.

You can convert it to all different kinds of datatypes. Check this documentation if you want to know more: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bignumber/